# RecordType changes when importing via REST API

Tags: rest-api, api, data-loader

I have this strange problem where if I import a Lead via REST API, the recordtype is changed from the one I specified in my JSON payload to a different one (and oddly, not even the default recordtype for the profile being used). I've verified there are no process builders or Apex that could be causing this change.

Here's the real interesting part - if I import that same lead via Data Loader or Salesforce Inspector, the recordtype is set appropriately to the value in the CSV.  Has anybody else seen an oddity like this?

Comment: Have you setup a debug to confirm no automations are running?

Comment: Is there a default record Type user has set in their my settings (different than the one set on profile)? Check that, it might be the reason.